# Растет время выполнения sql запроса

Tags: sql, sql-server, кэширование

Есть таблица без индексов, раз в сутки все строки удаляются,а потом в нее записываются данные (около 20 000 строк).
И есть процедура, которая апдейтит эту таблицу на основе ее же данных.

Проблема в том, что с каждым запуском, время работы пакета увеличивается на пару минут. Если таблицу дропнуть и создать заново - все приходит в норму, а затем время выполнения опять растет (изначально - 2.5 минуты).

Что с этим поделать? Может какой-то кэш очищать? Не хотелось бы пересоздавать таблицу постоянно

Comment: А вы строки удаляете, надеюсь с помощью `truncate table` ?

Comment: Нет, delete, а есть разница?

Comment: @DeRibura разница есть. Если хотите очистить таблицу, и затем залить туда новые данные, используйте лучше `truncate table; commit;`

Comment: Почитал) разница есть, попробую, может поможет